# How to insert a word between in a string mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I want to insert a string 'Rs.' Between a string 'pendrives above 2501'. So the output would be 'pendrives above Rs.2501'

**Now Result from mysql Query**

```
    SELECT id,
    url,  replace(substring_index(replace(url, '-', ' '),
                '/pendrive/',
                - 1),
        'in india.php',
        '') as pagetitle
FROM
    sitemap
where
    category_id = 9 and (url like '%under%' or url like '%above%')

id            url                      pagetitle
1    pendrive-above-2501.php       pendrive above 2501
1    pendrive-below-500.php        pendrive below 500
1    pendrive-below-700.php        pendrive above 700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(PAGETITLE,
                 '(pendrive above)', 'pendrive above RS.')from Isitemap
WHERE
    category_id = 9 and (url like '%under%' or url like '%above%');

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE `table_name`
 SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

From multiple tables-

If you want to edit from all tables, best way is to take the dump and then find/replace and upload it back.